# Disable site visiting and user logins excepting for a specific user

Tags: multisite, login, user-access

I want to disable temporarily site visiting and user logins to a multisite blog for the site maintenance time, excepting for super-admins and for a specific user. I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/81970/25187) function (thanks @joshc) and it works very well, but I don't know how to add the specific username to it so it can visit the site too. Please help!

This is what I tried, but without success, the user *test_user* is not allowed to login:

```
function site_maintenance() {
    global $user_login;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if ( !is_super_admin() || $user_login != 'test_user' ) {
        $logout_url = wp_login_url().'?mode=maintainance';
        wp_logout();
        wp_redirect( $logout_url, 302 );
        die();
    }     
}
add_action('get_header', 'site_maintenance');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` case matches any user who is not both a super admin and `test_user`.

For example, given a user `test_user` who is not superadmin, the result would be

```
if (true || false) redirect
```

Since one condition is true, the redirect would be triggered. Using the `&&` operator, you'd get

```
if (true && false) redirect.
```

Since both are not true, it doesn't trigger the redirect.

Comment: But `&&` will mean that *test_user* must be a super admin, or not? Anyway, I will try what you suggest, thank you!

Comment: Thank you, Jeremiah! With your help my function now works as expected!